# Spring Cloud DataFlow server runnning locally pointing to Skipper in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I am working on  spring cloud dataflow stream app. I am  able to run Spring cloud data flow server locally with the skipper running in Cloud Foundry with below configuration . Now i am trying to run the same with the skipper running in  kubernetes cluster. How can i specify the same ?

**manifest.yml**

```
    ---
    applications:
      - name: poc-scdf-server
        memory: 1G
        instances: 1
        path: ../target/scdf-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        buildpacks:
        - java_buildpack
        env:
          JAVA_VERSION: 1.8.0_+      
          JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'      
          SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_URL: 
          SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_ORG: <org>
          SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_SPACE: <space>
          SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_DOMAIN: <url>
          SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_USERNAME: <user>
          SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_PASSWORD: <pwd>          
   SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_CONNECTION_SKIPSSLVALIDATION: true
   SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI: <skipper_url>   SPRING_CLOUD_GAIA_SERVICES_ENV_KEY_PREFIX:spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.cloudfoundry.accounts[default].connection.
```

Answer (score 1):

In v2.3, we have recently added the platform-specific `docker-compose.yml` experience for the Local mode. You can find the new files [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server).

With this infrastructure, you could start SCDF locally, but also bring the platform accounts for CF, K8s, or even both! See [docs](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.3.0.SNAPSHOT/installation/local/docker-customize/#multi-platform-support).

You can also use the [`DockerComposeIT.java`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/integration/test/DockerComposeIT.java) to bring thigs up and running with automation, as well.

Comment: Tried as per the same getting below error Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. services is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "services" in API group  Seems its not getting the username from the same?

Comment: Most likely your user account doesn't have admin right on the K8s cluster; perhaps also check to make sure SCDF's service account is created on the desired namespace. This is nothing to do with SCDF itself, but it has to do with the cluster configuration.

Comment: I'm curious about your use-case here. Why are you running SCDF locally and interested in deploying streams/tasks in cloud platforms? This is not recommended anyway - so, curious that's why. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: i hv custom dataflow server image on top of the base image and local run helps debuggin also help skip the step to build image and push to registry eveytime .