# Spring Cloud Data Flow: Error org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am trying to run/configure a Spring Data Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) to schedule a task for a Spring Batch Job.

I am running in a minikube that connects to a local postgresql(localhost:5432). The minikube runs in a virtualbox where I assigned a vnet thru the --cidr, so minikube can connect to the local postgres.

Here is the postgresql service yaml:
https://github.com/msuzuki23/SpringCloudDataFlowDemo/blob/main/postgres-service.yaml

Here is the SCDF config yaml:
https://github.com/msuzuki23/SpringCloudDataFlowDemo/blob/main/server-config.yaml

Here is the SCDF deployment yaml:
https://github.com/msuzuki23/SpringCloudDataFlowDemo/blob/main/server-deployment.yaml

Here is the SCDF server-svc.yaml:
https://github.com/msuzuki23/SpringCloudDataFlowDemo/blob/main/server-svc.yaml

To launch the SCDF server in minikube I do the following kubectl commands:

```
kubectl apply -f secret.yaml
kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml
kubectl apply -f postgres-service.yaml

kubectl create -f server-roles.yaml
kubectl create -f server-rolebinding.yaml
kubectl create -f service-account.yaml
kubectl apply -f server-config.yaml
kubectl apply -f server-svc.yaml
kubectl apply -f server-deployment.yaml
```

I am not running Prometeus, Grafana, Kafka/Rabbitmq as I want to test and make sure I can launch the Spring Batch Job from SCDF. I did not run the skipper deployment ([Spring Cloud DataFlow server runnning locally pointing to Skipper in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612455/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-runnning-locally-pointing-to-skipper-in-kubernetes)) it is not necessary if just running tasks.

This is the error I am getting when trying to add an application from a docker private repo:

[image: Add Application Error]

And this is the full error stack from the pod:
https://github.com/msuzuki23/SpringCloudDataFlowDemo/blob/main/SCDF_Log_Error

Highlights from the error stack:

```
2021-07-08 13:04:13.753  WARN 1 --- [-nio-80-exec-10] o.s.c.d.s.controller.AboutController     : Skipper Server is not accessible
    org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:7577/api/about": Connect to localhost:7577 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:7577 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Postges Hibernate Error:

```
2021-07-08 13:05:22.142  WARN 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2021-07-08 13:05:22.200 ERROR 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
2021-07-08 13:05:22.214 ERROR 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
```

The first couple of errors are from the SCDF trying to connect to the skipper, since it was not configured, that was expected.

The second error is the Postgres JDBC Hibernate. How do I solve that?
Is there a configuration I am missing when setting the SCDF to point into the local postgres?

Also, in my docker jar I have not added any annotation such as @EnableTask.

Any help is appreciated, thx! Markus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search on

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
> "hibernate_sequence" does not exist   Position: 17

And found this stackoverflow anwer:

[Postgres error in batch insert : relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist position 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771730/postgres-error-in-batch-insert-relation-hibernate-sequence-does-not-exist-po)

Went to the postgres and created the hibernate_sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq_gen START 1;
```

Then, add application worked.